# Simplify LINQ to Create Step Values

Tags: c#, linq

Assume the following definition:

```
public class DataPoint {
    public DateTime Date { get; private set; }
    public double Value { get; private set; }
    public DataPoint(DateTime date, double value) { Date = date; Value = value; }
}
```

If `var points = ... //a date ordered list of DataPoints`

I want to convert `points` into a list or array that represents the steps between each subsequent value. E.g. `[3, 5, 6, 10.5]` would go to `[3, 2, 1, 4.5]` with dates.

Here's what I have:

```
var steps = (new[] {points.First()})
              .Concat(points
                        .Skip(1)
                        .Zip(points, 
                            (curr, prev) => new DataPoint(curr.Date, curr.Value - prev.Value)))
```

I think my ruby background might have gotten the best of me as that doesn't seem very readable. Any thoughts on how to make things more approachable?

Comment: I would use a foreach loop + a local var

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In my opinion, the `Concat` part is what's throwing it off. There is a lesser utilized `Select` overload that provides access to the index, which could be used like so (ignoring the `DataPoint` part to make a minimal example):

```
double[] points = new double[] { 3, 5, 6, 10.5 };

points.Select ((p, i) => p - (i == 0 ? 0 : points[i - 1]));
```

Comment: Phenomenal, the `Select` overload is nice but the gravy was really in the ternary usage. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You might want to consider doing your pairing first, which could then be extracted into an extension method. Not sure about terminology here.

```
public static class EnumerableExtension
{
    public static IEnumerable<Tuple<T, T>> Pairwise<T>(
        this IEnumerable<T> enumerable,
        T leadingItem)
    {
        new T[] { leadingItem }.Concat(enumerable).Zip(enumerable, Tuple.Create);
    }
}
```

And then your code would look something like this

```
var points = GetAllTheDataPoints();
var steps = points.Pairwise(leadingItem: DataPoint.Zero)
    .Select(t => new DataPoint(t.Item2.Date, t.Item2.Value - t.Item1.Value));
```

Where `Datapoint.Zero` is just a `DataPoint` with value 0.
If you want to make things even more explicit you could introduce your own `Pair<T, T>` type rather than using `Tuple<T, T>` since the property names `Item1` and `Item2` are kinda meh.

Comment: Something like this would be preferred over my answer if it would get a lot of reuse in a codebase. Used in one place, I think more people would directly understand something using framework linq methods if it was concise enough. Jon Skeet actually has a `PairWise` extension method in his MoreLinq library that makes use of `Func` types instead of `Tuple` for easier lambda expressions: https://code.google.com/p/morelinq/source/browse/MoreLinq/Pairwise.cs?r=3a7f001aed279b2b2ef9215ed0e149c7716b8872

Answer (score 1):

This is my proposed solution:

```
private static IEnumerable<double> Deltas(IEnumerable<double> sequence)
{
    var prev = 0.0;
    foreach (var item in sequence)
    {
        yield return item - prev;
        prev = item;
    }
}
```

The advantage of this version over @Ocelot20's is that it doesn't force your collection to implement `IList`, meaning

- it's more reusable, and
- it doesn't force you to have the sequence in memory all at once.

Answer (score 0):

You want to find substraction beetwen i[0] - 0, i[1] - i[0], ... which can be solved by creating new enumeration

```
    int[] points1 = { 3, 5, 6, 10 }; // points[0], points[1], points[2], points[3]
    int[] points0 = { 0, 3, 5, 6 };  //         0, points[0], points[1], points[2]
```

To create points0 I need to add int = 0 at start.

```
    int[] points = { 3, 5, 6, 10 };

    var steps = new int[] { 0 }.Concat(points)
                               .Zip(points, (x1, x2) => x2 - x1);
```

Overall when I need to use indexes I usually stick to for loop.